# Email Service, inbound email handler sending email on success = true

Tags: apex, apex-email-service

We have an email service set up with the basic code as per the docs.

My Email Service looks like:

```
global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope)
{
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();

    ...
    do a bunch of stuff
    ...

    result.success = true;
    result.message = emailObj.Id;
    return result;
}
```

My understanding is if the `result.successs == false`, an email is sent to the sender with the `result.message` as the body.

What we're seeing is the sender is always receiving an email, even though it's impossible for the success to be false.

This is happening in both a sandbox and production.

Has anyone come across this before?  Is there a known solution?

NOTE: I've ruled out a workflow/process builder as the cause of this email by adding some text to the `result.message`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely re-producable and appears to be a defect with Salesforce.

To reproduce:

Create an Email Service with class:

```
global class myHandler implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
      global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {
          Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();
          return result;
      }
  }
```

If you send an email to this Email Service, it will work fine.

As soon as you add in a `result.message = 'some text';`, it will *always* reply to the sender with that message.

The solution is to not set a `result.message` when you don't want an email sent to the sender.

Not cool Salesforce.